# Tools:Context error in 2 xml files

Tags: android-studio

```
tools:context="com.example.alondra.p1.RegisterActivity">

tools:context="com.example.alondra.p1.RegisterActivity">
```

these are my two errors

This is what it tells me in more detail

```
Error:(11, 61) cvc-elt.1.a: Cannot find the declaration of element 'LinearLayout'.
Error:(1, 56) s4s-elt-schema-ns: The namespace of element 'x' must be from the schema namespace, 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'.
Error:(1, 56) s4s-elt-invalid: Element 'x' is not a valid element in a schema document.
Error:(1, 56) schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'null', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not <xsd:schema>.
```

and this is for the other one

```
C:\Users\Alondra\AndroidStudioProjects\xxxxxx\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_register.xml
Error:(9, 61) cvc-elt.1.a: Cannot find the declaration of element 'LinearLayout'.
Error:(1, 56) s4s-elt-schema-ns: The namespace of element 'x' must be from the schema namespace, 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'.
Error:(1, 56) s4s-elt-invalid: Element 'x' is not a valid element in a schema document.
Error:(1, 56) schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'null', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not <xsd:schema>.
```

Comment: Add your XML file.  Apart from that try, File -> Invalidate Caches/ Restart.

Comment: Currently restarting I will update you on the results

Comment: So are you using the NDK? If not, can you show me the local.properties file.

Comment: @Sac where would that be located?

Comment: In your project pane, select the app module, and then start typing local.properties , you would find the file , post the contents of that file.

Comment: @Sac sdk.dir=C\:\\Users\\Alondra\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk

Comment: That is fine. Add your layout files. That might give some clue.

Comment: @Sac I posted the xml files below

Answer (score 0):

Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
NDK is missing a "platforms" directory.
If you are using NDK, verify the ndk.dir is set to a valid NDK directory.  It is currently set to C:\Users\Alondra\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle.
If you are not using NDK, unset the NDK variable from ANDROID_NDK_HOME or local.properties to remove this warning.

this is the error I get from my gradle console

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> <TextView
>     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
>     android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
>     android:text="Positive + 1"
>     android:textSize="30sp"
>     android:padding="20dp"
>     android:textColor="@color/Black" />
>
> <EditText
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
>     android:maxLines="1"
>     android:id="@+id/etEmail"
>     android:hint="Email"
>     android:textColorHint="@color/Black"
>     android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
>     android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
>     android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
>     android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>
>
> <EditText
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:id="@+id/etPass"
>     android:inputType="textPassword"
>     android:hint="Password"
>     android:textColorHint="@color/Black"
>     android:maxLines="1"
>     android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
>     android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
>     android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>
>
> <Button
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:id="@+id/btnLogin"
>     android:text="Login"
>     android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
>     android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
>     android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
>     android:onClick="Login" />
>
> <Button
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:id="@+id/btnReg"
>     android:text="Register"
>     android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
>     android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
>     android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
>     android:onClick="register"
>     />
> ```

Here is the other one

> ```
> <TextView
>     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:text="Welcome Back"
>     android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
>     android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
>     android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
>     android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
>     android:id="@+id/tvEmail"/>
>
> <RelativeLayout
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="match_parent"
>     android:orientation="horizontal">
>
> <Button
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:id="@+id/btnLogout"
>     android:text="Log Out"
>     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
>
> </RelativeLayout>
>  </LinearLayout>
> ```

and here is the last one

> ```
> <TextView
>     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
>     android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
>     android:text="Positive + 1"
>     android:textSize="30sp"
>     android:padding="20dp"
>     android:textColor="@color/Black" />
>
> <EditText
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
>     android:maxLines="1"
>     android:id="@+id/etEmail"
>     android:hint="Email"
>     android:textColorHint="@color/Black"
>     android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
>     android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
>     android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
>     android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>
>
> <EditText
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:id="@+id/etPass"
>     android:inputType="textPassword"
>     android:hint="Password"
>     android:textColorHint="@color/Black"
>     android:maxLines="1"
>     android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
>     android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
>     android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>
>
>
> <Button
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:id="@+id/btnReg"
>     android:text="Register"
>     android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
>     android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
>     android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
>     android:onClick="register"
>     />
>
> <TextView
>     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
>     android:text="Back to Login"
>     android:id="@+id/tvLogin"
>     android:textColor="@color/Black"
>     android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
>     />
> ```